# Getting error when trying to set Azure Event Hub capture settings with PowerShell Set-AzEventHub cmdlet

Tags: powershell, settings, capture, azure-eventhub

I am trying to use PowerShell to set up an Event Hub with Capture set. However, I am experiencing problems when trying specify the capture settings with `Set-AzEventHub`. I have the following script commands:

```
$ehResourceGroup = 'kv-audit-resource'
$location = 'eastus'
$ehNameSpace = 'kv-audit-eh'
$ehName = 'security-logs'
$partitions = 1
$week = 7
# Creat resource group for hub
New-AzResourceGroup -Name $ehResourceGroup -Location $location

# Create namespace for hub

New-AzEventHubNamespace -ResourceGroupName $ehResourceGroup -NamespaceName $ehNameSpace -Location $location

# Make the hub
New-AzEventHub -ResourceGroupName $ehResourceGroup -NamespaceName $ehNameSpace -Name $ehName -PartitionCount $partitions -MessageRetentionInDays $week

# Get hub info
$loggingEventHub = Get-AzEventHub -ResourceGroupName $ehResourceGroup -NamespaceName $ehNameSpace -Name $ehName

# Add capture info
$loggingEventHub.CaptureDescription = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Commands.EventHub.Models.PSCaptureDescriptionAttributes
$loggingEventHub.CaptureDescription.Enabled = $true
$loggingEventHub.CaptureDescription.IntervalInSeconds  = 60
$loggingEventHub.CaptureDescription.Encoding  = "Avro"
$loggingEventHub.CaptureDescription.SizeLimitInBytes = 10485763
$loggingEventHub.CaptureDescription.Destination.Name = "EventHubArchive.AzureBlockBlob"
$loggingEventHub.CaptureDescription.Destination.BlobContainer = "cyberstorageaccount2"
$loggingEventHub.CaptureDescription.Destination.ArchiveNameFormat = "{Namespace}/{EventHub}/{PartitionId}/{Year}/{Month}/{Day}/{Hour}/{Minute}/{Second}"
$loggingEventHub.CaptureDescription.Destination.StorageAccountResourceId = "/subscriptions/{SubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/$ehResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ClassicStorage/cyberstorageaccount2"

# Now update the hub with capture info
Set-AzEventHub -ResourceGroupName $ehResourceGroup -Namespace $ehNameSpace -Name $ehName -InputObject $loggingEventHub
```

I execute the first three commands to create the Event Hub without problems. The storage account, `cyberstorageaccount2`, already exists. I wait until the Azure dashboard shows that the Event Hub is successfully made and active, which takes several minutes. When I execute the last two commands to modify the capture settings, I get:

```
PS C:\> $loggingEventHub = Get-AzEventHub -ResourceGroupName $ehResourceGroup -NamespaceName $ehNameSpace -Name $ehName
>> $loggingEventHub.CaptureDescription = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Commands.EventHub.Models.PSCaptureDescriptionAttributes
>> $loggingEventHub.CaptureDescription.Enabled = $true
>> $loggingEventHub.CaptureDescription.IntervalInSeconds  = 60
>> $loggingEventHub.CaptureDescription.Encoding  = "Avro"
>> $loggingEventHub.CaptureDescription.SizeLimitInBytes = 10485763
>> $loggingEventHub.CaptureDescription.Destination.Name = "EventHubArchive.AzureBlockBlob"
>> $loggingEventHub.CaptureDescription.Destination.BlobContainer = "cyberstorageaccount2"
>> $loggingEventHub.CaptureDescription.Destination.ArchiveNameFormat = "{Namespace}/{EventHub}/{PartitionId}/{Year}/{Month}/{Day}/{Hour}/{Minute}/{Second}"
>> $loggingEventHub.CaptureDescription.Destination.StorageAccountResourceId = "/subscriptions/{SubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/$ehResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ClassicStorage/cyberstorageaccount2"
>> Set-AzEventHub -ResourceGroupName $ehResourceGroup -Namespace $ehNameSpace -Name $ehName -InputObject $loggingEventHub
Set-AzEventHub : Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'
At line:11 char:1
+ Set-AzEventHub -ResourceGroupName $ehResourceGroup -Namespace $ehName ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (Microsoft.Azure...ExecuteCmdlet():ErrorResponseException) [Set-AzEventHub],
   ErrorResponseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SubCode=40000. StorageAccountResourceId. TrackingId:ea7e4590-486a-4597-9351-b5e8508857b8
   _M6CH3_M6CH3_G28, SystemTracker:kv-audit-eh.servicebus.windows.net:security-logs, Timestamp:2020-12-08T12:37:56 Co
  rrelationId: 4b1edeed-6585-47f0-b14e-476614404a23,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.EventHub.Commands.EventHub.SetAzureEven
 tHub
```

What am I doing wrong? It looks like it's griping about the storage account, but when I display the contents of `$loggingEventHub.CaptureDescription.Destination.StorageAccountResourceId`, the path appears correct.

Thanks in advance for any info.

Answer (score 0):

Storage resource-id seems malformed. It is missing 'storageaccounts' segment.

"/subscriptions/{SubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/$ehResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ClassicStorage/**storageAccounts**/cyberstorageaccount2"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. That was one of many things I had wrong wth this set up.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work. My code was based on an example provided by Microsoft, but their example assumed you had set up a lot of things previously. What follows is my PowerShell code that fills in some of the gaps in their example. The code is commented (slightly) and has debug output that you can delete. It assumes that you have already made an Event Hub with the prerequisite resource group and namespace.

```
$ehResourceGroup = 'kv-audit-resource'
$location = 'eastus'
$ehNameSpace = 'kv-audit-eh'
$ehName = 'security-logs'
$partitions = 1
$week = 7
$kvStorageAccount = 'cybersecurityaccount2'
$kvContainer = 'security-container'


# Create the storage account for the Event Hub
Write-Output("Create storage account $kvStorageAccount")
$storageAcct = New-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ehResourceGroup -AccountName $kvStorageAccount -Location $location -SkuName Standard_GRS -Kind BlobStorage -AccessTier Cool

# Get the "context" required for the container
$accountContext = $storageAcct.Context

# Create a container for the storage account
Write-Output("Create storage account container $kvContainer")
New-AzStorageContainer -Name $kvContainer -Context $accountContext -Permission 'Container'

# Get the storage account ID for the Event Hub
Write-Output("Get ID of storage account $kvStorageAccount")
$kvStorageAccountId = (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ehResourceGroup -Name $kvStorageAccount).Id

# Get Event Hub object
Write-Output("Get Event Hub object")
$loggingEventHub = Get-AzEventHub -ResourceGroupName $ehResourceGroup -Namespace $ehNameSpace -Name $ehName

# Update Event Hub capture description
Write-Output("Update Event Hub object")
$loggingEventHub.CaptureDescription = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Commands.EventHub.Models.PSCaptureDescriptionAttributes

$loggingEventHub.CaptureDescription.Enabled = $true
$loggingEventHub.CaptureDescription.IntervalInSeconds  = 60
$loggingEventHub.CaptureDescription.Encoding  = "Avro"
$loggingEventHub.CaptureDescription.SizeLimitInBytes = 10485763
$loggingEventHub.CaptureDescription.Destination.Name = "EventHubArchive.AzureBlockBlob"
$loggingEventHub.CaptureDescription.Destination.BlobContainer = $kvContainer
$loggingEventHub.CaptureDescription.Destination.ArchiveNameFormat = "{Namespace}/{EventHub}/{PartitionId}/{Year}/{Month}/{Day}/{Hour}/{Minute}/{Second}"
$loggingEventHub.CaptureDescription.Destination.StorageAccountResourceId = $kvStorageAccountId

Set-AzEventHub -ResourceGroupName $ehResourceGroup -Namespace $ehNameSpace -Name $ehName -InputObject $loggingEventHub

Write-Output($loggingEventHub)
```